# Time complexity of Tsp using DP

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, traveling-salesman

this is the recursion formula for problem :

```
C(i,S) = min { d(i,j) + C(j,S-{j}) }
```

In fact, when I tried to implement it as a code, the following code came to my mind:

```
int TSP(i, S){
    if(S.size == 0)
    return dist(start_vertex,i)
min = inf
cost = inf
  for(int j=0;j<S.size;j++)
     {
      cost = dist(i,S[j])+TSP(j,S-{j});
      if(cost < min)
       min = cost;
      }
global_cost+=min;
return min;
}
```

Because this `for` compares n times to find the minimum, it means its recursion as:

```
T(n) = nT(n-1)+n ==> T(n) = O(n!)
```

Because each step we compare to find the minimum size of size S is, of course, the code is factorial. So what does it have to do with the subset and So why the complexity of time in the form of (n^2*2^n)? And what is the proof of its time complexity?

Comment: Next time I suggest taking a look at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is known as the Held–Karp algorithm, and is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), and also mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms) on the traveling salesman problem.

Your implementation of the algorithm is wasteful. Using memoization, there are only at most $n2^n$ inputs. Since TSP runs in time $O(n)$ ignoring recursive calls, when using memoization, the total running time will be $O(n^22^n)$.

Comment: doesn't this implementation exactly correspond to the dp algorithm? So why is it factorial?

Comment: Right, thanks. Your implementation doesn't use dynamic programming.